# Cannot open or save files from within applications

Tags: pantheon-files

Whenever you click on one of those "Browse" or "Open" or "Save As" buttons, a small Files window will launch and you either look for a file to open up or a place to save one.

Sometimes that functionality disappears, most noticeably in Scratch but also in other applications. The relevant Open or Save button is gone and I can't even overwrite files to override the problem.

I've tried installing other file managers and set them to default but this made no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by overriding xsettings:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/DialogsUseHeader': <0>, 'Gtk/ShellShowsAppMenu': <0>, 'Gtk/DecorationLayout': <'close:menu,maximize'>}"
```

File chooser dialog has minimum size much bigger after running that command. This could be annoying.

Also this is duplicate of this post: gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/DialogsUseHeader': <0>, 'Gtk/ShellShowsAppMenu': <0>, 'Gtk/DecorationLayout': <'close:menu,maximize'>}"